# Does SPE (Single Pair Ethernet) require termination?

Tags: ethernet, bus, termination, serial-bus

It is stated that it needs 100 ohm termination resistor but is it end of the each line externally?

Comment: Can you cite where you're at that also can you provide the standard for single pair ethernet (and just to be sure we're not talking about standard ethernet)?

Comment: @VoltageSpike https://www.single-pair-ethernet.com/en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are series resistors on the TX and RX lines, but no parallel termination, this is the method of coupling.

[image]
Source: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snla395/snla395.pdf

If no power is used then this is the method:

[image]
Source: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/dp83td510e.pdf

Note that Rt1 and Rt2 are not loaded